# scheme procedure path that takes an integer n and a BST that contains integer n

Tags: scheme

Write a Scheme procedure path that takes an integer `n` and a binary search tree `bst` that contains the integer `n`, and returns a string of ones and zeroes. A move left corresponds to a character zero `('0')` and a move right corresponds to a character one `('1')`.

For example:

```
(path 17 '(14 (7 () (12 () ()))
(26 (20 (17 () ())())(31 () ()))))
"100".
```

In the above example, we get strings 100 as we find the path. I had tried but my path is incorrect.

Comment: Please add to the question the code you've written so far. Otherwise, it sounds like you're asking people to do your homework ;)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the code you've written so far, so I'll sketch the answer so you can fill-in the blanks with your own solution. Assuming that `n` is in the tree:

```
(define (path n bst)
  (cond ((< <???> n) ; if the current element is less than n
         (string-append "1" <???>)) ; append 1, advance recursion to the right subtree
        ((> <???> n) ; if the current element is greater than n
         (string-append "0" <???>)) ; append 0, advance recursion to the left subtree
        (else        ; we found n
         <???>)))    ; base case, end recursion with empty string
```

The trick is to traverse the tree and accumulate the answer at the same time; given that the output is a string we build it along the way using `string-append`.